# Convert simple jQuery to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullscreen

Can anyone convert this jQuery code to JavaScript for me? because my library i'm using can't use jQuery and i don't know anything about it.

Here it is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.fs-button').on('click', function(){
    var elem = document.getElementById('fullscreen');
    if (document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    } else {
        elem.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    };
}); });
```

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it just asks for a solution the OP can easily figure out himself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [addEventListener](http://help.dottoro.com/ljeuqqoq.php)

```
function addEventListenerByClass(className, event, fn) {
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
        //Attach event
        list[i].addEventListener(event, fn, false);
    }
}

//Iterate and attach event againts class name
addEventListenerByClass('fs-button', 'click', myfunction); 

function myfunction(){
    var elem = document.getElementById('fullscreen');
    if (document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    } else {
        elem.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    };
}
```

Comment: As long as you're only targeting IE versions from 9 onwards, this would work.  You should probably also put this code in a `onload` event handler e.g. on the `body` element.

Answer (score 0):

**in html**

```
<button onclick="myfunction()" class="fs-button">Click</button>
```

**in JS**

```
function myfunction(){
 var elem = document.getElementById('fullscreen');
    if (document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    } else {
        elem.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    };
}
```

Comment: But as a sidenote: the `on` function of jQuery will automatically add this event to later/dynamically added elements with class name `fs-button`, what this JS-version will not.

Comment: You're thinking of the three-argument version of `on`.